# Trouble with CreateFileMapping

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use a C API in my C++ Qt application, but it requires some modifications. I'm not extremely familiar with the WinAPI or C++ in general and I'm running into some issues.

```
    // create the name of our file-mapping object
    nTry++; // Ensures a unique string is used in case user closes and reopens
    wsprintf(szName, FS6IPC_MSGNAME1 ":%X:%X", GetCurrentProcessId(), nTry);

    // create the file-mapping object
    m_hMap = CreateFileMapping(
                    (HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFF, // use system paging file
                    NULL,               // security
                    PAGE_READWRITE,     // protection
                    0, MAX_SIZE+256,       // size
                    szName);            // name
```

The definition for FS6IPC_MSGNAME1 is in another file:

```
#define FS6IPC_MSGNAME1      "FsasmLib:IPC"
```

szName is a `wchar_t` type.The error I am currently receiving (from the wsprintf line) is:

```
cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [19]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `CreateFileMapping`, and everything to do with `wsprintf`. You are passing a narrow string literal where a Unicode string is expected. Try `wsprintf(szName, L"" FS6IPC_MSGNAME1 ":%X:%X", ...)` but I'm not sure MSVC handles concatenation with mixed-width literals correctly.

Comment: While you're at it, pass `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` as the first parameter of [`CreateFileMapping()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) toforce a page-file-backing. *Especially* if you're planning even a remote chance of building this on a winx64 implementation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Now it says concatenating mismatched strings

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried this and it makes my program hang and crash.

Comment: Okay, so I got rid of all the errors by adding A on the end of wsprintf and CreateFileMapping, but not the CreateFileMapping returns null.

Comment: What's `MAX_SIZE`? What does `GetLastError` return right after `CreateFileMapping` fails?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `MAX_SIZE` is `#define MAX_SIZE 0x7F00`. `GetLastError` returns 6.

Comment: That would be `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. This suggests to me that you **are** in fact building a 64-bit build, and you **must** in fact pass `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` as the first argument rather than a hardcoded 32-bit value of `0xFFFFFFFF`, as @WhozCraig (and the function's documentation) recommends.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I do that, but now my program crashes and burns. The error is in this code: http://pastebin.com/TbnCFicR at the `CopyMemory()` line. The error is with memcpy.asm. My debugger says it is with this part of memcpy (I've no idea what it means): `0x7feec7fab86  <+0x0076>         mov     dword ptr [r10],eax`

Comment: This means that one or more of `pHdrR`, `pHdrR->pDest` and `m_pNext` are invalid pointers. Debug your program, find out which.